# Anylogic: Delay in Transfer of Agent Between Enter and Exit Blocks

Tags: anylogic

I am simulating a job-shop scheduling problem where an order is processed by multiple machines located across different manufacturers. Each manufacturer
[image: Image of Manufacturer Agent]

and machine
[image: Image of Machine Agent]

is represented as an agent in separate populations. Part of the simulation is the transport of an order agent from a manufacturing agent to the relevant machine agent according to the production plan.

As part of another part of my program, I need to predict the times when the order is generated by the source block when each order should enter and exit the relevant machine agent.

I am running into an issue where the time when the order agent exits the exitToTransport block in the manufacturer, agent does not match with the time that the order agent enters the enterMachine block for the machine agent.

[image: Code for exitToTransport]

[image: Code for enterMachine]

This issue seems to only appear after the order has undergone 2-3 of these transports. Additionally, there are no blocks that the order agent enters or leaves between the exitToTransport and enterMachine blocks. Is there a way to eliminate this gap between the exit and enter times? Thank you for your time.

Comment: There cannot be any delay between them by design. You probably traceln not the same order, did you try to traceln the order ID or something similar? Else, is there something blocking the flow downstream of the enter block that may have an effect? (should still not affect the timing, though)

Comment: Also, try to test your model with only 1 order? Reduce whatever complexity you can to get the root problem :)

Comment: @Benjamin Thank you for the suggestions.  The trace is linked to the order ID, and when there is only 1 order, the times match up. However, when I increase the concurrent orders in the system, the disparity in the times exist in the last two transports of the order. I not sure why the times would match for the first 2-3 transports of an order and not for the last ones when multiple other orders exist in the system.  I don't believe anything should be blocking the order from entering the enter block since I have max capacity in the delay and seize block that follow the enter block.

Comment: When you say "The trace is linked to the order ID" that is not shown in your screenshots. There, you only output the times. Did you really print the ID along to check? Really sounds like you mix up orders and get confused. But hard to say, you need to strip this further and go deeper investigating yourself, I am afraid. I can only assure you: there can never be a delay between and Exit-Enter flow :)

Comment: @Benjamin. Apologies for the miscommunication. I meant that after your suggestion in the first comment I updated the trace to be linked to the order_id and only output for the first order;  I am still faced with the same issue. Thanks for your help, and I will try to strip down the code even more.